# Using expression matching inside a string

Tags: python, python-re

I'm using `imap_tools` package to download attachments from my mail.
To search for emails that I want to be included I use the function as described in documentation.

```
messages = mb.fetch(criteria=AND(seen=False, from_="email@test.com"), mark_seen=True, bulk=True)
```

How can I use expression matching in that case to find any mail from `@test.com` domain? I mean something like below but working:

```
messages = mb.fetch(criteria=AND(seen=False, from_="\w+@test.com"), mark_seen=True, bulk=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND(from_="@test.com")
```